# how to decode this JSON string?

Tags: php, json

this is what i get as a string from a feed finder url (JSON Encoded):

```
{
  "updated": 1265787927,
  "id": "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dhttp://itcapsule.blogspot.com/\u0026output\u003djson",
  "title": "Feed results for \"http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/\"",
  "self": [{
    "href": "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q\u003dhttp://itcapsule.blogspot.com/\u0026output\u003djson"
  }],
  "feed": [{
    "href": "http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"
  }]
}
```

How can i decode it using json_decode() function in php and get the last array element ("feed") ? i tried it with the following code but no luck

```
 $json = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/feed-finder?q=http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/&output=json");
 $ar = (array)(json_decode($json,true));
 print_r $ar;
```

Please help ..

Comment: Apologies if I am misunderstanding but don't you just want $ar['feed'] ?

Comment: There is no need in type casting in PHP.

Comment: @Jasonbar,

Yes u are correct. I need only the "feed" value.

Comment: `(array)` in front of `json_decode()` is not needed. And it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$feed = $array['feed'];
```

Note that [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) already returns an array when you call it with `true` as second parameter.

**Update:**

As the value of `feed` in JSON

```
"feed":[{"href":"http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"}]
```

is an array of objects, the content of `$array['feed']` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [href] => http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
        )  
)
```

To get the URL you have to access the array with `$array['feed'][0]['href']` or `$feed[0]['href']`.

But this is basic handling of arrays. Maybe the [Arrays documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) helps you.

Comment: @Felix,

Now I am getting the result as "Array" :(