# How to transform a JSON String into PHP array

Tags: php, json

A JSON string is sent via a HTTP request to my webservice, it looks like this:

```
[\"Mairie\",\"Préfectures et sous-préfectures\"]
```

How can i do to make a simple `php array` in which i can perform  `php arrays functions` such as `implode`.

I tried this but it didn't transform the JSON String into an array:

```
    $list=json_decode($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"],true);
```

**EDIT:**

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"], true));   
$var=json_decode($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"],true);
$in_list = "'".implode("','", $var)."'";
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $in_list);//in the text file i got this empty string: ''
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6dbHBxGU Well, probably I'm extra lucky? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to decode this JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235374/how-to-decode-this-json-string)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = "[\"Mairie\",\"Préfectures et sous-préfectures\"]";
var_dump(json_decode($var, true));

/*result:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Mairie"
  [1]=>
  (33) "Préfectures et sous-préfectures"
}
*/
```

Works fine, please do `var_dump($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"])`

Comment: But i need to store the return of the `var_dump` into an array to process it later, the `var_dump` didin't give a return.

Comment: @Malek You can just do what you did as `$list=json_decode($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"],true)`, `var_dump` is just for showing the result.

Comment: @xdazz, This is strange. This doesn't work for me with the accented letters. Do you know what php setting I need to fix?

Comment: @Walkerneo Please note that `json_decode` only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: @xdazz: please have a look on my EDIT.

Comment: @Malek Post your var_dump result of `$_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"]`

Comment: Ho can i do that, i don't use the curl

Comment: @Malek　It has no matter with curl, just add `var_dump($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"])` right before `$var=json_decode($_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"],true);`

Comment: It is returning me this: `string(44) "["Mairie","Pr�fectures et sous-pr�fectures"]" `

Comment: @Malek So it seems your `$_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"]` is not UTF-8 encoded, that will be the reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6988/discussion-between-xdazz-and-malek)

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code:

```
$str = "[\"Mairie\",\"Préfectures et sous-préfectures\"]";
var_dump(json_decode($str,true));
```

You will get:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Mairie"
  [1]=>
  string(33) "Préfectures et sous-préfectures"
}
```

So are you sure your `$_POST["The_JSON_Parameter"]` has the same value i.e. a string literal `"[\"Mairie\",\"Préfectures et sous-préfectures\"]"` ?