# How to get "Name":"x","Name2":"x2" into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to decode this JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235374/how-to-decode-this-json-string)

When fetching data from another site I get this

```
{"user_id":"908508","item_id":"341","quantity":"3","status":"0"}
```

sometimes theres more fields, sometimes there's less

how can I turn this into an array

```
"name" => "X"
```

Comment: http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = "http://...";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE /** forces to decode into PHP array */);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't hear about json before so I didn't know where to look.

Answer (score 4):

Use json_decode

```
json_decode($jsonstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php